# How to make this loop

Tags: python, loops

I simply cannot figure out how to get this program to ask me if I want to start over. I know it's simple but I can't get the syntax right for anything I try. I want it to keep looping at F or C   I'll try to solve how to break. Thank you for your patience.

```
temp=input('input F or C:  ')
if temp=='F':
    print('convert Fahenheit to C')
    F=int(input("What are degress F:  "))
    c=(F-32)*(5/9)
    print(c)
elif temp=='C':
    print('convert C to F')
    C=int(input("What degrees C would you like to convert to F?  "))
    F=(C*9/5)+32
    print(F)
```

Comment: Put `while True:` at the top and indent everything one level more. `break` to break out.

Answer (score 1):

```
while True:
    temp=input("(F)->C, (C)->F, or (Q)uit: ")
    if temp.lower() == "f":
        f = float(input("Enter temperature in Fahrenheit: "))
        c = (f-32)*(5.0/9.0)
        print(c)
    elif temp.lower() == "c":
        c = float(input("Enter temperature in centigrade: "))
        f = (c*9.0/5.0) + 32.0
        print(f)
    elif temp.lower() == "q":
        break
```

You are on dangerous terrain with the `5/9` and `9/5`: In python 2.x, this is an integer division, so `5/9 == 0`, while in python 3.x this will be converted to float.

(You are using `input`, which I think means that you are running python 3.x, but still you should be careful to make sure you know whether something is integer or float.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution (using python 2.x):

```
temp = None
while temp != 'Q':
    temp=raw_input('input F or C (Q to quit):  ')
    if temp=='F':
        print('convert Fahenheit to C')
        F=int(raw_input("What are degress F:  "))
        c=(F-32)*(5.0/9.0)
        print(c)
    elif temp=='C':
        print('convert C to F')
        C=int(raw_input("What degrees C would you like to convert to F?  "))
        F=(C*9.0/5.0)+32
        print(F)
```